# Is multiple user account required to deploy in office 365 production environments?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, solution-deployment

Let’s say there are 5 users working with different apps in one SharePoint 2013 Office 365 development environment. Naturally they are working with different user ids (a/c). Now if they want to deploy i.e. implement same thing in the production server do they need to have 5 different user account or id in the production environment or even with 1 id also they can deploy same thing?

Answer (score 0):

As Far i Know, if all developer using the same account at different times then they can deploy the apps to the Office 365.

Check below link for more information.

http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2012/08/14/how-to-deploy-apps-to-office365-preview.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179811(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Both the link shows way with Visual Studio. If want to deploy OOB web parts, is Visual studio necessary?